# Problems with view controllers going into the background of UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabBarController with 3 view controllers connected to it. Everything works fine apart from when you switch from one view to another, the new view takes a moment to reload what it was doing. I know this isn't such a big deal but it just makes the app look a bit sloppy. Does anyone know how I can keep the app running in the background, or something so that it doesn't have to reload each time.

As you might have noticed I'm very new to Objective-C so I can understand if I'm being unclear but any help is really appreciated!

EDIT: FOR DAVID

This is the code for the stopwatch in the .m file:

```
@implementation StopwatchViewController

- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    isCounting = false;
}

- (IBAction)startOrStop:(id)sender
{
    if (self->isCounting == false) {
        self->isCounting = true;
        [self startStopwatch];
    } else {
        self->isCounting = false;
        [self stopStopwatch];
    }
}

- (void)startStopwatch
{
    [startStopButton setTitle:@"STOP" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self performSelector:@selector(stopwatch) withObject:self afterDelay:1.0];
}

- (IBAction)resetStopwatch:(id)sender
{
    [self reset];
}

- (void)stopwatch
{
    if (self->isCounting == false) {
        return;
    } else {

    NSInteger hourInt = [hourLabel.text intValue];
    NSInteger minuteInt = [minuteLabel.text intValue];
    NSInteger secondInt = [secondLabel.text intValue];

    if (secondInt == 59) {
        secondInt = 0;
        if (minuteInt == 59) {
            minuteInt = 0;
            if (hourInt == 23) {
                hourInt = 0;
            } else {
                hourInt += 1;
            }
        } else {
            minuteInt += 1;
        }
    } else {
        secondInt += 1;
    }

    NSString *hourString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", hourInt];
    NSString *minuteString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", minuteInt];
    NSString *secondString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", secondInt];

    hourLabel.text = hourString;
    minuteLabel.text = minuteString;
    secondLabel.text = secondString;

    CGRect hourFrame = self->hourBar.frame;
    CGRect minuteFrame = self->minuteBar.frame;
    CGRect secondFrame = self->secondBar.frame;

    if ((NSInteger)hourFrame.size.height != hourInt) { // check if we need to modify
        hourFrame.origin.y -= ((hourInt * 10.0) - hourFrame.size.height);
        hourFrame.size.height = (hourInt * 10.0);

        self->hourBar.frame = hourFrame;
    }

    if ((NSInteger)minuteFrame.size.height != minuteInt) { // check if we need to modify
        minuteFrame.origin.y -= ((minuteInt * 4.0) - minuteFrame.size.height);
        minuteFrame.size.height = (minuteInt * 4.0);

        self->minuteBar.frame = minuteFrame;
    }

    if ((NSInteger)secondFrame.size.height != secondInt) { // check if we need to modify
        secondFrame.origin.y -= ((secondInt * 4.0) - secondFrame.size.height);
        secondFrame.size.height = (secondInt * 4.0);

        self->secondBar.frame = secondFrame;
    }

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(stopwatch) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    }
}

- (void)stopStopwatch
{
    [startStopButton setTitle:@"START" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

- (void)reset
{
    [startStopButton setTitle:@"START" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    self->isCounting = false;

    hourLabel.text = @"00";
    minuteLabel.text = @"00";
    secondLabel.text = @"00";

    CGRect hourFrame = self->hourBar.frame;
    CGRect minuteFrame = self->minuteBar.frame;
    CGRect secondFrame = self->secondBar.frame;

    hourFrame.size.height = 0;
    minuteFrame.size.height = 0;
    secondFrame.size.height = 0;

    hourFrame.origin.y = 321.0;
    minuteFrame.origin.y = 321.0;
    secondFrame.origin.y = 321.0;

    self->hourBar.frame = hourFrame;
    self->minuteBar.frame = minuteFrame;
    self->secondBar.frame = secondFrame;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

SECOND EDIT FOR DAVID:

Changed the main parts of the code to look like this:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:YES];
    [self swapFrames];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    [self updateBars];
}

- (void)stopwatch
{
    if (self->isCounting == false) {
        return;
    } else {

    hourInt = [hourLabel.text intValue];
    minuteInt = [minuteLabel.text intValue];
    secondInt = [secondLabel.text intValue];

    if (secondInt == 59) {
        secondInt = 0;
        if (minuteInt == 59) {
            minuteInt = 0;
            if (hourInt == 23) {
                hourInt = 0;
            } else {
                hourInt += 1;
            }
        } else {
            minuteInt += 1;
        }
    } else {
        secondInt += 1;
    }

    NSString *hourString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", hourInt];
    NSString *minuteString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", minuteInt];
    NSString *secondString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", secondInt];

    hourLabel.text = hourString;
    minuteLabel.text = minuteString;
    secondLabel.text = secondString;

    [self swapFrames];
    [self updateBars];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(stopwatch) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    }
}

- (void)updateBars
{
    if ((NSInteger)hourFrame.size.height != hourInt) { // check if we need to modify
        hourFrame.origin.y -= ((hourInt * 10.0) - hourFrame.size.height);
        hourFrame.size.height = (hourInt * 10.0);

        self->hourBar.frame = hourFrame;
    }  

    if ((NSInteger)minuteFrame.size.height != minuteInt) { // check if we need to modify
        minuteFrame.origin.y -= ((minuteInt * 4.0) - minuteFrame.size.height);
        minuteFrame.size.height = (minuteInt * 4.0);

        self->minuteBar.frame = minuteFrame;
    }

    if ((NSInteger)secondFrame.size.height != (secondInt * 4.0)) { // check if we need to modify
        secondFrame.origin.y -= ((secondInt * 4.0) - secondFrame.size.height);
        secondFrame.size.height = (secondInt * 4.0);

        self->secondBar.frame = secondFrame;
    }
}

- (void)swapFrames
{
    hourFrame = self->hourBar.frame;
    minuteFrame = self->minuteBar.frame;
    secondFrame = self->secondBar.frame;
}
```

I separated the code so that just before the view appear it should update the bars. However, it did not work. I did some investigating by printing out the values of some of the variables at certain points. It appears that in viewWillAppear, secondBar.frame (and minuteBar, etc.) has updated to the correct height. However, in viewDidAppear, that value is reset to 0. This does not happen to secondInt, or secondFrame. Somewhere between those two methods the frame is reset but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: have you created any synchronous request to server in your ViewDidLoad method.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really know what that means!

Comment: I mean are you fetching any data from server or implemented any NSURL instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, the frames for your properties `self.hourBar`, `self.minuteBar` and `self.secondBar` are set to 0 when you switch between tabs, and only update them every second.

If this is indeed the case, just set them to their correct values in your viewControllers `viewWillAppear:` method (assign them to some property in `viewWillDisappear:`).

As a sidenote, you seem to be coming from C++. The "->" notation is very uncommon for Objective-C, since properties are accessed with ".", and their corresponding instance variable with "->". Using the arrow notation will **not** call the auto-synthesised getter/setter methods of properties!

Also, is there a specific reason why you always create new `NSTimer` objects instead of setting `repeats:` to yes? Creating a timer and adding it to a runloop (which `scheduledTimerWith:...` does) is a relatively costly operation.

Comment: Sorry, I realise I wasn't great to explain it. It's fine when it first loads up because, due to the nature of the views, the all require a button to be pressed to start the processes. However, when I then change views and go back to that view, it takes a moment to load up again.

Comment: Oh, I understand now, sorry. I'm not sure what kind of 'processes' you are talking about, could you elaborate some more? Do these processes need to run in the background or is it just the UI that needs to be updated quickly?

Comment: My app is basically a clock app, and one of my views is a stopwatch. The stopwatch takes the time and presents it as an animating bar (as in it grows as time progresses). However, when i switch back to that view, for a moment the bar is not visible until the next second, in which it jumps to that point and continues.

Comment: This sounds like you unload something in `viewWillDisappear` or `viewDidDisappear`, or update the UI in `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewWillAppear`. It's hard to give a general answer without seeing any of your code though.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36353/discussion-between-user2397282-and-david)

Comment: I figured out a way to get it to work! I separated the code; in viewWillDisappear, I use temporary variables to store the frames of the bars, and in viewDidAppear, I quickly change the height of the bars. I have decided to accept your answer because you practically gave me the answer, I just had to adapt it to my app. Thanks again David!!